# Converting an ENVI raster as point shapefile for editing in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, vector, envi

I have an ENVI raster with multiple classes inside. I tried to export this to a vector so that I can convert it to a shapefile in ArcGis (I want to manually edit/delete points in the raster), but the resulting .dbf file only has the following columns:

> OID | Class Name | Class_Id | Parts | Length | Area

It doesn't have x & y coordinates. How can I fix this and/or what are the other ways that I can export this ENVI raster to an editable point shapefile in ArcGis? Is this even the proper approach?

Comment: Try to get it converted to a GeoTiff or other common format then use Raster to Point in ArcCatalog to create points.. it could potentially be a lot of points though. I haven't used ENVI yet so I don't know what it's capable of.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Raster to Point](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=1439&pid=1436&topicname=Raster_to_Point_%28Conversion%29) conversion tool in ArcMap is the first thing that comes to mind, it should give you a point in for every raster cell you have (placed in the middle of the cell) and then you can edit the points as you want.

You could also take a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19040/how-to-convert-raster-data-into-regularly-sampled-points) for alternative methods.

There is also a [Raster to Vector](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/RasterToVector.html) tool in `ENVI` that you can try, though I'm not sure how well it deals with point conversions.

Comment: Thanks for this. I always end up with a messy and unclassified shapefile with conversion methods. I've searched for a few more methods and [ARIS](http://www.aris.nl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=210:aris-grid-editor-for-arcmap&catid=64:arcgis-tools&Itemid=161) is the best one for me (albeit pricey).

Comment: You are trying to do classification on the raster?

Comment: Nope, I am trying to clean up my post-classification raster. It's just that the conversion methods seems to lose the layers of my raster.

Comment: In that case [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25120/manually-edit-a-raster-to-improve-a-classification) will help