# Error in .bboxCoords(coords) : nrow(coords) > 0 is not TRUE using raster::sampleRandom()

Tags: raster, r, samplepoints

I am trying to sample a raster (pixel values= 1 or NA, where 1 means opportunity as defined for my research).

The specs of my raster are

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 15838, 3808, 60311104  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 60, 60  (x, y)
extent     : 2402625, 2631105, 788651, 1738931  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : <folder> not including in this post 
names      : <name> not including in this post 
values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
```

I want to sample 30 random points in all pixels with value=1 for further analyses and research.

```
sampled_points <-raster::sampleRandom(above raster, size = 30 ,na.rm=TRUE, xy=TRUE, sp= TRUE)
```

But the Error in .bboxCoords(coords) : nrow(coords) > 0 is not TRUE is present. I have used sampleRandom() multiple times before in other analyses an dhave not encountered this problem. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I can only generate that error if all the cells in a raster are NA. How many non-NA cells are there? Sometimes the min/max reported can be lying, especially for large rasters. What's `table(yourraster)` say for itself?

Comment: I used length(getValues(myraster==1)) and length(getValues(is.na(myraster))) and get 60311104, same as ncell for both pixel values. I cannot use table(myraster) because of error- unique() applies to vectors

Comment: @Spacedman- I couldn't figure out a solution. I reclassified all NA pixels to 0 and used sampleStratified() varying size and exp to sample and ignore all sampled points in pixels=0

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion about sampling rasters with a large number of NAs: [Using sampleRandom() from large raster without NA values in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80904/using-samplerandom-from-large-raster-without-na-values-in-r)

In short, this can lead to problems even if not all cells have NA values, but also if the number of NA is large and the sample size small so that  a lot of NAs are drawn in the sampling process. A solution can be to produce a larger sample and then downsample from the actual values we obtain.